# How to group equal information from query sql result in php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have some data from two tables, and the are connected by the column `PersonId` and each person can have multiple cards, and I need to have one output like:

```
Card 1 expiry date XX-XX-XX
Card 4 expiry date XX-XX-XX
E-mail: XX@XX.com
Card 2 expiry date YY-YY-YY
Card 3 expiry date YY-YY-YY
E-mail: YY@YY.com
```

Instead of what I'm getting which is the email for every card.

```
Card 1 expiry date XX-XX-XX
E-mail: XX@XX.com
Card 4 expiry date XX-XX-XX
E-mail: XX@XX.com
Card 2 expiry date YY-YY-YY
E-mail: YY@YY.com
Card 3 expiry date YY-YY-YY
E-mail: YY@YY.com
```

I need it because I will send emails with the info, and I don't want to send one e-mail to each card, I will have to make one function to send all cards of the same client in one e-mail.

My sql query is the following:

```
SELECT Crt.PersonId, Crt.CrtType, Crt.CrtNr, Crt.CrtValidFrom, 
        Crt.CrtValidUntil, Crt.CrtLastTNr, PersonAdd.PersonId AS Expr1, 
        PersonAdd.Email, Crt.CodDate
FROM Crt 
    INNER JOIN PersonAdd ON Crt.PersonId = PersonAdd.PersonId
WHERE (Crt.CrtValidUntil <= CAST(DATEADD(DD, 7, GETDATE()) AS Date))
ORDER BY Crt.CrtNr ASC
```

And if necessary I'm testing the output with this code:

```
while ($rows = $stm->fetch())
    {
        $CPersonUId = isset($rows['PersonId']) ? $rows['PersonId'] : NULL;
        $CType = isset($rows['CrtType']) ? $rows['CrtType'] : NULL;
        $CNr = isset($rows['CrtNr']) ? $rows['CrtNr'] : NULL;
        $CValFrom = isset($rows['CrtValidFrom']) ? $rows['CrtValidFrom'] : NULL;
        $CValUntil = isset($rows['CrtValidUntil']) ? $rows['CrtValidUntil'] : NULL;
        $CLTCCTime = isset($rows['CrtLastTNr']) ? $rows['CrtLastTNr'] : NULL;
        $CLTPEmail = isset($rows['Email']) ? $rows['Email'] : NULL;


        echo "Card nº<b>".$CNr."</b> valid until <b>".$mytime1."</b></br>";
        echo $CLTPEmail."</br>";

    }
```

And the results are the following:

```
Card nº1 valid until 15/11/2018
email@email.com
Card nº2 valid until 15/11/2018
email@email.com
```

Instead of:

```
Card nº1 valid until 15/11/2018
Card nº2 valid until 15/11/2018
email@email.com
```

Comment: `Group by email `

Comment: Ok, so that query does not produce that output, so show us the PHP code you are using to process the query output please

Comment: @RiggsFolly added the PHP code, I was editing my topic because I thought it was better to understand if I placed some code.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I already tested with that but got one SQL error I tested like this `...GROUP BY PersonAdd.Email  ORDER BY Crt.CrtNr ASC` and the SQL gives me the following error `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Crt.PersonId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple variable to remember which email you are dealing with should solve this nicely

```
$last_email = null;

while ($rows = $stm->fetch()) {

    $CPersonUId = isset($rows['PersonId']) ? $rows['PersonId'] : NULL;
    $CType = isset($rows['CrtType']) ? $rows['CrtType'] : NULL;
    $CNr = isset($rows['CrtNr']) ? $rows['CrtNr'] : NULL;
    $CValFrom = isset($rows['CrtValidFrom']) ? $rows['CrtValidFrom'] : NULL;
    $CValUntil = isset($rows['CrtValidUntil']) ? $rows['CrtValidUntil'] : NULL;
    $CLTCCTime = isset($rows['CrtLastTNr']) ? $rows['CrtLastTNr'] : NULL;
    $CLTPEmail = isset($rows['Email']) ? $rows['Email'] : NULL;

    if ( $last_email == null ) {
        $last_email = $CLTPEmail;
    }
    if ( $CLTPEmail != $last_email ) {
        echo $last_email . "</br>";
        $last_email = $CLTPEmail;
    }

    echo "Card nº<b>".$CNr."</b> valid until <b>".$mytime1."</b></br>";

}
// put out the last email 
echo $last_email . "</br>";
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same result as before but now with one warning: `Warning: Use of undefined constant CLTPEmail - assumed 'CLTPEmail' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in...`

Comment: Yes, look again at line `if ( $CLTPEmail != $last_email ) {` I missed the `$` from `CLTPEmail` on the original edit. I fixed it now

Comment: Got it, but somehow it does not show the e-mail now

Comment: Hmmm let me look, I must have made a woops :)

Comment: Ahh, see the `f ( $CLTPEmail != $last_email ) {
        echo $last_email . "</br>";
        $last_email = $CLTPEmail;
    }` I was outputing the wrong email

Comment: Still not working but I believe the problem is here `if ( $CLTPEmail != $last_email )` because the first time you run it the `CLTPEmail` is not different from `last_email` so he will skip it and don't echo the email.

Comment: That is because you said you wanted the card No lines to appear before the email line

Comment: But the e-mail is not appearing at all

Comment: How many results are you getting ? And for how many emails? Oh I also forgot to put the last email out, so if you are testing this with only one email that edit should fix it

Comment: I was testing only with one e-mail that was the thing, you did it :D thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep your query, then you'll have to use php to manipulate the result and put it together inside PHP object or array.

i usually use php assoc array to do something like that

```
$data = [];
while ($rows = $stm->fetch())
{
   if(isset($data[$rows['PersonId']]) {
     //use personId as the array key
     $data[$rows['PersonId']] = ['email' => $rows['Email'], 'cardList'=> [] ];
   }
   //add cardNr to CardList property wich also an array
   $data[$rows['personId']] ['cardList'] [] = $rows['CrtNr'];
}

//check using print_r
print_r($data);
```

But you can actually use the query to get similar result, using GROUP BY and some GROUP CONCAT to cobine value from multiple fields, in SQL server group concat is similar to STRING_AGG .

Don't take my query as it is, since i don't tested it on Sql server, don't have have, but the query should similar to this

```
SELECT Crt.PersonId, Crt.Email,
STRING_AGG(CONCAT(CrtNr.,'#',CrtValidFrom,'#',CrtValidUntil ), ',') as card_info
FROM Crt 
INNER JOIN PersonAdd ON Crt.PersonId = PersonAdd.PersonId
WHERE (Crt.CrtValidUntil <= CAST(DATEADD(DD, 7, GETDATE()) AS Date))
GROUP BY Crt.Email
ORDER BY Crt.CrtNr ASC
```

STRING_AGG is similar function to GROUP CONCAT in Mysql
https://database.guide/the-sql-server-equivalent-to-group_concat/

Comment: I don't mind in changing my query, I just don't know what to change on it to make it work

Comment: i add rough query example that show the used of GROUP BY and STRING_AGG

Comment: Can't make it work, after search the errors that I'm getting on SQL some people say it could be because of the SQL version the one I'm using is the 2008 R2